# Angular if-else condition is not executing correctly

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this function where I check with 2 jsons, and if there is a match, I set one of the json key value to 'false'

```
compare(list,res):void{
    for (let k = 0; k < list.enrolments.length; k++) {
    console.log("Compare " + list.enrolments[k].id+ " and " + res.id);

      if (list.enrolments[k].id=== res.id) {
        list.enrolments[k].match= res.id;
        console.log("Match! " + list.enrolments[k].id+ " " + res.id); 
      } else {
        console.log("No! " + list.enrolments[k].id+ " " + res.id);
        list.enrolments[k].match= 'false';
      }
    }
  }
```

```
The console.log prints out:
Compare 2844 and 1751
  No! 2844 2781
Compare 1751 and 1751
  **Match! 1751 2781**
Compare 2839 and 1751
  No! 2839 2781
Compare 1753 and 1751
  No! 1753 2781
Compare 2844 and 1753
  No! 2844 2630
Compare 1751 and 1753
  No! 1751 2630
Compare 2839 and 1753
  No! 2839 2630
Compare 1753 and 1753
  **Match! 1753 2630**
```

Note that there is 2 matches above.

However, when I tried to print out my list json,
I get this in return:

```
0:
enrolments: Array(2)
0: {id: 2844, match: "false"}
1: {id: 1751, match: "false"}
nameId: 1750


1:
enrolments: Array(1)
0: {id: 2839, match: "false"}
nameId: 1916

2:
enrolments: Array(1)
**0: {id: 1753, match: 2630}**
nameId: 1144
```

There is only one match. [0][enrolments][1] should be a match as well, but it's returning false.
Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: How come you have two matches where on compare line you have one value for res.id and another one on the match line?

Comment: Maybe something to do with missing nested for loop. Your data is 2d your algorithm is 1d

Answer (score 0):

Where are you printing the json? can you add your objects as well.
My compare function would look like this

```
 compare(list, res): any {
       list.enrolments = list.enrolments.map(enrolment => enrolment.match = 
      (enrolment.id === res.id) ? res.id : false);
      return list;
}
```

Comment: I called it in this:

functionA{
  for (let i =0; i < x.length; i++){
    compare(x,y)
 }
console.log(this.list)
}

Comment: @somebodyelse can you call the above function and and check the list object ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is , it seems, you are calling function multiple times and each time you are calling, you are over-writing previous match. Update your function to:

```
compare(list, res): void {
  for (let k = 0; k < list.enrolments.length; k++) {
    console.log("Compare " + list.enrolments[k].id + " and " + res.id);

    if (list.enrolments[k].id === res.id) {
      list.enrolments[k].match = res.id;
      console.log("Match! " + list.enrolments[k].id + " " + res.id);
    } else if (list.enrolments[k].match == undefined || list.enrolments[k].match == null) { // this will make sure to not override previous match
      console.log("No! " + list.enrolments[k].id + " " + res.id);
      list.enrolments[k].match = 'false';
    }
  }
}
```